# CryptoJS encryption has empty spaces

Tags: javascript, typescript, encryption, cryptojs

I am using CryptoJS to encrypt and decrypt data, the issue is that sometimes the encryption process leaves m with empty spaces, eg.

`U2FsdGVkX1 2mZClrIaVdRSXYQi9XQGU6AGLmE xIv8UOHz9c6KBiGydo9r4BI6v`

and this makes it impossible to decrypt since it's gonna be an empty string in the end.

Sometimes it doesn't have white spaces and it can be successfully decrypted, so I figured out this was the issue.

this is how I encrypt and decrypt the data

```
const encryptedData = AES.encrypt(
  spotifyId,
  this.configService.get('ENCRYPT_KEY'),
).toString();
console.log('encrypted', encryptedData);
const decryptedParam = AES.decrypt(
  encryptedData,
  this.configService.get('ENCRYPT_KEY'),
).toString(enc.Utf8);
console.log(decryptedParam);
```

Edit:
After running the script from @Topaco

> ciphertext:
> edf322d5807824fca4dbca0d37adf476453f8ed2f3ab784cbf86a64831ff244833c73c6105f012aa9e042f1ed5259e71
> salt:           a910b44631c78c50
> key:            88433d6ad1241af9d85a85cf14c3d1f8e76d5159dea2e6e9e89529eef8b03c24
> iv:             bfdb9d30403b340a451ecbfef0b151cf
> openssl format: U2FsdGVkX1+pELRGMceMUO3zItWAeCT8pNvKDTet9HZFP47S86t4TL+Gpkgx/yRIM8c8YQXwEqqeBC8e1SWecQ==

it seems like the empty spaces are not showing up anymore when I am using his script

This is the version I am using for crypto js   "crypto-js": "^4.1.1", straight from package.json

Comment: None of those have this issue

Comment: Maybe for some reason the /, + and = characters of the Base64 alphabet are not output in your environment. To verify this, please run the [following script](https://jsfiddle.net/3u9psfzr/) in your environment until the problem occurs and share the result (preferably at the end of your question and not in comments). There are several CryptoJS forks. Which fork do you use (share a link).

Comment: `+` in particular represents space when URL-encoding comes into the picture. Like if you want to search for ***some question*** with Google, the URL is going to be https://www.google.com/search?q=some+question - but the code you share doesn't involve any URL encoding, and actually it works for me, displaying `+` in the console log properly.

Comment: the code I provided happens in the same controller in my NestJS API, so there shouldn't be any encoding issues. Also when I am sending it to my frontend I am encoding it, but the issue happens before that.